# how to open external url in new tab in laravel

Tags: javascript, html

I opened the external URL using javascript. But it opens in the same window I need to open it in new tab

```
onclick="window.location= '$url';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using only **html** if you want :

`<a href="my.link.com" target="_blank"> some text </a>`

But by **javascript** this should work :

`onclick="window.open('http://my.link.com', '_blank')"`